# What would be CFG for all strings which does not contain bbb?

Tags: context-free, formal-grammars

Is there a way to get complement? Following is my solution for CFG of all strings that DON'T contain bbb.

```
S -> aA | aaB | aB | bA | bbA
A -> aA| aB
A -> epsilon
B -> bA | bbA
B -> epsilon
```

Is this right?

Comment: The answer-checking part of your question is off-topic since saying "yes" or "no" isn't much use to you and is very unlikely to be useful to anyone else in the future. Please read related meta discussions [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/597/) and [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/519/) and adjust your question accordingly, e.g. by formulating a specific question about a single element of your answer you are uncertain about.

Comment: Are you sure you want "context-free"? Your language and your grammar are regular (well, at least you could easily make them regular).

Comment: The empty word $\epsilon$ is in your language since it does not contain $bbb$, but your grammar does not allow for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The complement of a context-free language isn't necessarily context-free so there's no general method to produce a grammar for the complement.

Comment: Of course, in this case there is, since the language is regular and regular languages are closed under complement.

Answer (score 0):

Only one way to construct this CFG is that make DFA of the given problem then convert DFA to Grammar that will be a regular grammar and we know every regular grammar is CFG also [**By Chomsky classification**].

So following will be the production of the required grammar:

S => aS/bA/a/b
A => aA/bB/a/b
B => aB/bC/a
C => aC/bA/b

for any query in this regards feel free to contact me.